# How do you view a long whatsapp profile message

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Some people on whatsapp have a short profile message like "Hi, I am using Whatsapp". Other people have a long profile message like "An apple a day keeps the doctor away so that the bad things don't come out and play".

But it only shows part of their long message. How do I view the whole of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the contacts list, tap the photo of the contact in question. This pops up a larger version of the photo, with three icons at the bottom: a message, a telephone, and an information 'i'. Tapping the 'i' takes you to a contact information screen, which includes the full status message.

Answer (score 0):

As per [FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/23740821):

> The status message is a real time indicator of what you are doing, so
>   that you can keep up to date with your contacts. You can view status
>   messages by opening WhatsApp and going to the Favorites / Select
>   contact screen. Your friend's status message will be displayed
>   directly below their name.
>
> It may take some time for your newly updated status message to display
>   on your friends' phones. If your friends refresh their Favorites /
>   Select contact list, they will see the status update much more
>   quickly.

Comment: You've just quoted a huge chunk and not addressed what I said. I can see part of the message that others have put on their profiles, just not the whole of it